# Order of operations when loading data in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, etl, pandas-datareader

I have got `dtype` error on a row that should have been excluded by  `skiprows` parameter. So, is it correct that data type validation/coercion happens before skipping rows? Is there a way to bypass errors on such to-be skipped rows?

Similarly, when are `converters` applied? A flow chart of such order dependent operation would be helpful.

Here is the example:

```
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO("i,a,b\ngood,1,2\nbad,3,a"), 
pd.read_csv(data, index_col='i',skiprows=lambda index: 'bad' == index, dtype={'b':float})
```

The above throws

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
```

Without skipping data should be:

```
    a, b
--------
good 1, 2
bad  3, a
```

After skipping, I expected

```
    a, b
---------
good 1, 2
```

**Update:**
Seems also to be related to this [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9435) about dtype/index_col not in sync.

Comment: sample data and expected output ?

Comment: I am adding minimal example, was in cell phone!

Comment: updaed the minimal example.